# Fixing dihedral angles beyond 180 degrees limit to create smooth curves

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry, angle

I have an output from a commercial program that contains the dihedral angles of a molecule in time. The problem comes from apparently a known quadrant issue when taking cosines, that your interval is -180 to 180, and I am not familiar with. If the dihedral would be bigger than 180, this commercial program (SHARC, for molecular dynamics simulations) understands that it is bigger than -180, creating jumps on the plots (you can see an example in the figure bellow).
[image]
Is there a correct mathematical way to convert these plots to smooth curves, even if it means to go to dihedrals higher than 180?
What I am trying is to create an python program to deal with each special case, when going from 180 to -180 or vice versa, how to deal with cases near 90 or 0 degrees, by using sines and cosines... But it is becoming extremely complex, with more than 12 nested `if` commands inside a `for` loop running through the X axis.
If it was only one figure, I could do it by hand, but I will have dozens of similar plots.
I attach an ascii file with the that for plotting this figure.

What I would like it to look like is this:
[image]

Thank you very much,

Cayo Gonçalves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a pretty easy solution.

Numpy has the `unwrap` function. I just need to feed the function with a vector with the angles in radians.
Thank you Yves for giving me the name of the problem. This helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is called phase unwrapping.

As your curves are smooth and slowly varying, every time you see a large negative (positive) jump, add (subtract) 360. This will restore the original curve. (For the jump threshold, 170 should be good, I guess).

Comment: Hello Yves, thank you for your reply and giving me the name of the problem. Yes, I do that. But as you see in the figure that how it should look like, I might have more than 2 complete turns, which means angles higher than 720. So in these cases I need to add (subtract) 720 to the raw value. For that I need to test what is the previous correct angle and if it is positive or negative. I have to include also a condition if by any chance the molecule does more than 3 complete turns, in which case I add or subtract 1080...

Comment: @CayoEmilio: yes, that's what you have to do. Sorry, I made a typo, you must add/subtract multiples of 360.